# What is the maximum number of dichotomies in a square?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-learning-theory, vc-dimension

I am new to machine learning. I am reading [this blog post](http://me-ramesh.blogspot.com/p/machine-learning.html) on the VC dimension.

$\mathcal H$ consists of all hypotheses in two dimensions $h: R^2 → \{−1, +1 \}$, positive inside some square boxes and negative elsewhere.

An example.

[image]

My questions:

1. What is the maximum number of dichotomies for the 4 data points? i.e calculate mH(4)
2. It seems that the square can shatter 3 points but not 4 points. The $\mathcal V \mathcal C$ VC dimension of a square is 3. What is the proof behind this?

Comment: "What is the maximum number of dichotomies for the 4 data points?", but in the picture you're showing, there are 5 data points (or numbers).

Comment: The picture is just an example showing one of the possibilities of data points distributions. For point INSIDE the square, it is +1, For point OUTSIDE the square, it is -1.  My question is asking 4 points, it is correct and unrelated to 5 points in my drawing.

Answer (score 1):

- The number of dichotomies of 4 data points will clearly be $2^4 = 16$. According to these [slides](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~arce/files/Courses/StatLearning/5.%20Training%20vs%20Testing.pdf) the definition of dichotomy in context of Statistical Learning is:

> Different ‘hypotheses’ over the finite set of $N$ input points.

Which basically means hypotheses with **unique** behaviours over the input points. Two or more different hypotheses can have same behaviour on the data points (consider the case of a square covering the $4$ data points, an even larger square will also cover the $4$ data points. Thus they are different hypotheses but have same behaviour) and hence emphasis on the term **unique**.

- The proof of axis aligned squares having $\mathcal V \mathcal C$ dimension $3$ can be found [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/ml14/sol2.pdf). It's pretty straightforward so I don't want to explain it here.